# Java android - add multiple images from url to listview

Tags: java, android, xml, json, listview

In my app, I have a list view with the uploaded videos, and i'am getting it from JSON.
JSON also returns me the url to video image.
Now I'am trying to set that image into imageview of my xml layout listview but it only put the last image loaded for the first listview item

Here is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="460dp" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout> 

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#DCDCDC"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is XML for each listview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/videoImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxHeight="70dp"
        android:maxWidth="70dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoURL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoTitle"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/videoImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoViews"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoURL"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/videoImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And now my java class that loads videos and the class that is responsible for video image:

```
class LoadVideosFromDB extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(onlineVideos.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loadingVideos));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", token));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(getAllVideosURL, "POST",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Videos: ", json.toString());

        try { // Trying to get videos

            // Getting Array of videos
            videos = json.getJSONArray("videos");

            // Looping through all videos
            for (int i = 0; i < videos.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = videos.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                videoID = c.getString("videoID");
                videoTitle = c.getString("videoTitle");
                videoViews = c.getString("videoViews");
                videoDownloads = c.getString("videoDownloads");
                videoHashTag = c.getString("videoHashTag");
                videoNices = c.getString("videoNices");
                videoNok = c.getString("videoNok");
                videoThumbPath = "https://dev.oncom.ch/upload/thumbs/"
                        + c.getString("videoThumbPath");
                videoPath = "https://dev.oncom.ch/upload/videos/"
                        + c.getString("videoPath");
                videoCategorieID = c.getString("videoCategorieID");
                videoComments = c.getString("videoComments");

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put("videoTitle", videoTitle);
                map.put("videoViews", getString(R.string.viewed) + " " + videoViews + " " + getString(R.string.times));
                map.put("videoUrl", videoPath);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                videosList.add(map);

                GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
                task.execute(new String[] { videoThumbPath });

                Log.d("videos", String.valueOf(i));

            } // End for

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

                onlineVideos.this, videosList, R.layout.videos_list_item,
                        new String[] { "videoTitle", "videoViews","videoUrl" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.videoTitle, R.id.videoViews, R.id.videoURL }
                );

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                // dismiss the dialog after getting all videos
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    } // Close PostExecute

} // Close LoadVideosFromDB

//GetXMLTask - Used to get image from url
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        ImageView videoImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoImage);
        videoImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        int i = 0;
        Log.d("thumbs", String.valueOf(i));
        i++;
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
} //END OF GetXMLTask
```

Help please.
Thank you for your attention

Comment: U can try using picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) an image downloading and caching library instead of using your own async task. Implementation is very easy and library works great.

Answer (score 0):

use this, i use this, this works great https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: that's a little bit confusing

Comment: I just need help, to understand what I have to edit on my code

Comment: i suggest you to create your own adapter by extending BaseAdapter class. there in the getView method, put your code to set the image
see this for creating custom adapter http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/